# Rails app - Better to keep or delete obsolete data

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, activerecord

> **tl;dr** - At the bottom, I ask a couple general questions about smart database design that don't require reading the whole thing. So feel free to skip and take a look at those. Thanks!

I'm building a Rails web-app where, after some user input, I generate a number of options from which a user can choose one, which is then saved and associated with the user. This choice can occur a long time after the options are generated -- so the options need to be saved -- but once the choice is made, all the "incorrect" options are no longer relevant.

I have little knowledge of how databases work and what slows them down, so I'd really appreciate any input (as outlined below) about how to best accomplish this, given the conflicts I see in the approaches I've thought of.

It seems to me I have three paths I can take here:

1. Make options just instances of the `Choice` model, associated through a `belongs_to`/`has_many` with a user. When a user chooses one, its `id` is declared the `choice_id` of the user (and, potentially, the other options are disassociated from the user).

   > The main issue with this that I see is the exponential increase in the size of the `Choice` table which would result. This is a major table in my app, and I would like to keep it as quick as possible.
2. Following user input, I generate and save let's say 5 `Choice` objects, all of which `belong_to` the user, as `options`. Then, when the user chooses, four are deleted, and the fifth is associated as that user's single `choice`

   > The downside, as I perceive it, is that I end up with lots of "empty" rows in the database, so that the highest `choice_id` is significantly greater than the number of `choices` in the database. A boss I recently worked for gave the advice never to delete data, which obviously clashes with this approach.
3. I create a separate table for an `Option` model, which is, in practically every way, identical to the `Choice` model, because the options need to be fully rich stand-ins for a choice. These options `belong_to` a `user`, as per the above, but they're left to be when I one is chosen to graduate up to being a `choice`.

   (This is somewhat similar to [this older post's discussion of archiving by moving old data to a new table](http://propelorm.org/blog/2011/08/29/introducing-archivable-behavior-and-why-soft-delete-is-deprecated.html). Is this considered an OK practice? Seems ideal to me, but I don't know the potential downsides).

   > As I see it, this option preserves all data while keeping my main `Choice` table unencumbered by kruft unchosen data. Unfortunately, it adds a **major** duplication in the database, and a duplication of code as well (though I suppose I could have `Option` just inherit from `Choice`, which is weird, but whatever).

All of these opinions are completely uninformed by knowledge on database architecture and efficiency,  however, and I'd feel much better able to tackle the tradeoffs if I knew:

- Do deleted rows in a table slow down transactions like existing rows do? Less? At all? At what point does table size become a serious concern in a SQL database? Is it worth thinking about?
- What are best practices around deleting data? Is this a really bad idea?
- What are the best practices around duplicate tables? (i.e. tables with identical data structure, which are treated differently, for any of a number of reasons, from the original table).
- The broadest, least SO-appropriate, and most helpful question: How might you approach this issue, optimizing for the efficiency of the `Choice` table? (But also, as much as possible, avoiding duplication and following best practices).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

How about a small file prefixed with a '.' so it is hidden (in unix) placed in the users home directory.  If you output your options in a readable format this makes it easy to read and modify them.

You only want to use a database if performance or functionality justify it. If you require users to use a database that has to be installed, which the client may not appreciate having to do.

Comment: Thanks, Ian. Unfortunately, as this is for a database-backed web-application (so the database is installed on the server), and I don't have directories for separate users or anything like that, I don't think this solution is feasible, unless I misunderstand it. I'm definitely interested in something that's similarly caching-oriented, but I'm guessing a database is the most reasonable option in my case.